# Using external ENUM values in case statement

Tags: java, enums

I have a `enum` class:

```
public enum MessageEnum {
    HEADER,
    EXIT,
    LOGIN;
}
```

I receive a `String` message from a different app:

```
String msgHeader;
...
msgHeader = msgIn.get(MessageEnum.HEADER.toString()).asText();
```

How can I `switch` on `msgHeader` and `case` for the enums? `Java` says:
`case expressions must be constant expressions`:

```
while (msgHeader != MessageEnum.EXIT.toString()) {

            switch (msgHeader) {

            case MessageEnum.LOGIN.toString(): //Error in this line
                break;

            default:
                break;

            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `MessageEnum.LOGIN.toString()` will be evaluated at runtime, whereas `switch-case` expects the value of `cases` to be known at compile time. So, that won't work. Either you've to use hard-coded string - `"LOGIN"`, `"HEADER"`.

Another approach is to convert the `msgHeader` string to corresponding enum constant:

```
MessageEnum msgEnum = MessageEnum.valueOf(msgHeader);
```

Then `switch` on that value:

```
while (msgEnum != MessageEnum.EXIT) {
     switch(msgEnum) {
     case LOGIN:   // action
     case HEADER:  // action
     }
}
```